# Find the right value for which the expected value is minimized

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I'm preparing for my exams and I have a question: I know that to know if a function has a minimum or maximum, I have to take the first derivative and setting it to 0, and to know if it is a minimum or maximum i have to take the second derivative and if the result is >0 then it is a minimum and if the result is <0 I have a maximum, but I'm stuck with this exercise because I don't know how to check if it is a minimum or maximum.
the exercise is:

`Suppose X is a random variable with mean μ and variance > 0. For what value of a, where a > 0, is E([aX - 1/a]^2) minimised?`

Now I have all the steps and the solutions that is:

$$E(a^2X^2 + 2X + 1/a^2)
= a^2E(X^2)+ 2E(X) + 1/a^2$$

Now I take the derivative with respect to a and set it to 0

$\frac{d}{da} \{a^2E(X^2) + 2E(X) +1/a^2 \} = 2aE(X^2) - 2a^{-3}$

Setting it to 0

$2a(E(X^2)-a^{-4}$

Where we have two solutions

$2a = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0$

and

$a^{-4} = E(X^2)$

$a = 1/[E(X^2)]^1/4$

The problem is that if I take the second derivative to check if they are minimum or maximum, for the first one I have as result $2E(X^2) = 0$ and for the second one I have $8E(X^2) = 0$, and I think I did something wrong, because I took the second derivative, and substitute "a" with the value found in the first derivative set to 0

Comment: Shouldn't that be $-2X$ rather than $2X$ in your first step?

Comment: Yes. However, that doesn't affect any calculations or the final answer.

Comment: Dear Elena, welcome to Cross Validated. Since you know more-or-less how to write in $\LaTeX$ , try to rectify what you've written. Also, take note of the comment made by @fblundun .

Comment: @ElenaFranchini also worth pointing out that it's possible to classify stationary points of a function even when the second derivative is 0 using the [higher-order derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test).

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(a)=a^2\cdot E[X^2] - 2\cdot E[X] +\frac{1}{a^2}$

$f'(a) = 2a\cdot E[X^2] -\frac{2}{a^3}$

$f''(a) = 2\cdot E[X^2] +\frac{6}{a^4} > 0$

Therefore, wherever $f'(a) = 0$ , we may say that $f$ will be minimized, as $f''(a) > 0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, $$f'(a) = 0\quad\implies\quad a=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{E[X^2]}}$$ As it's given that $a>0$ , therefore $f$ will be minimized at $a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{E[X^2]}}$ .

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll write better the question the next time